# Порядок срабатывания событий, ajax

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь подключить шорткод только на отдельной странице, чтобы лишний код не выполнялся на всех страницах, но ajax не работает.
Можете объяснить порядок срабатывания хуков, почему в хуке `wp_enqueue_scripts` не срабатывает `wp_ajax_`?

```
function my_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
    $allowed_pages = [
        'about',
        'contact',
    ];
    if ( is_page( $allowed_pages ) ) {
        add_shortcode( 'cool_shortcode', 'cool_shortcode_callback' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cool-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/cool.js', [ 'jquery' ], '1.0', true );
        function cool_shortcode_callback( $atts ) {
            return 'cool';
        }
        function create_payment_form(){
            echo 'ok';
        }
        add_action('wp_ajax_create_payment_form', 'create_payment_form');
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_create_payment_form', 'create_payment_form');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_wp_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок загрузки WordPress несколько отличается при ajax и обычном показе страницы.

Что происходит при вызове ajax? Управление получает файл `admin-ajax.php`. Он производит инициализацию ядра и плагинов, подключая файлы `wp-load.php` -> `wp-config.php` -> `wp-settings.php`.

В то же время при обычной загрузке страницы, кроме этого, из `wp-blog-header.php` вызывается `wp()` (главный запрос WordPress) и `template-loader.php` (старт темы для вывода страницы).

Событие `wp_enqueue_scripts` создаётся во время события `wp_head`, которое создаётся функцией `wp_head()`. Это происходит, как легко догадаться из пояснений выше, только при обычной загрузке страницы.

Возвращаясь к вопросу, можно ответить так: при работе ajax файл `functions.php` темы читается, хук `my_wp_enqueue_scripts` добавляется в таблицу хуков, но никогда не выполняется. Потому что ajax не выводит заголовок страницы и не вызывает `wp_head()`.

Более того, функции типа `is_page()` не будут работать в ajax, потому что не выполнен главный запрос WordPress (не вызван `wp()`, см. выше).

Answer (score 1):

functions.php

```
<?php

$action = 'my_script';

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () use ($action) {

    wp_register_script ($action, get_stylesheet_directory_uri () . '/script.js');

    wp_localize_script (
        $action,
        'foo',
        [
            'ajax_url' => admin_url ('admin-ajax.php'),
            'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce ("{$action}_nonce"),
            'bar' => 'baz'
        ]
    );

    wp_enqueue_script ($action);
});

add_action ("wp_ajax_{$action}", function () use ($action) {

    if (wp_verify_nonce ($_POST ['_nonce'], "{$action}_nonce"))
        echo 'ok';

    wp_die ();
});
```

script.js

```
const data = new FormData ()
data.append ('_nonce', foo.ajax_nonce)
data.append ('action' , 'my_script')

fetch (foo.ajax_url, {method: 'POST', body: data}).then (r => r.text ()).then (alert)
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php wp_head (); ?>
    </head>
</html>
```